# toggling "active" to class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to toggle a class 'active' into my

currently i have this code:

```
class VideoListItem extends React.Component {

render() {
const {video, onVideoSelect} = this.props
const{} =this.props
const imageUrl=video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

return (
    <li onClick={() => onVideoSelect(video)} className="list-group-item">
        <div className="video-list media">

            <div className="media-left">
                <img className="media-object" src={imageUrl} />
            </div>

            <div className="media-body">
                <div className="media-heading">{video.snippet.title}</div>  
            </div>

       </div>
    </li>
)
}
```

}

So eventually I would get "list-group-item active" aftert clicking on that li.
The problem is that I have another function that runs onClick.
I tried this approach

```
class VideoListItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          animate: false
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }

      handleClick(e) {
        // modify the state, this will automatically recall render() below.
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return { animate: !prevState.animate }
        });
      }
    onClick(event) {
        () => onVideoSelect(video);
        this.handleClick;
     }
    render() {
    let animationClasses = (this.state.animate ? ' active': '');
    const {video, onVideoSelect} = this.props
    const imageUrl=video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

    return (
        <li className={`list-group-item${animationClasses}`} onClick{this.onClick} >
            <div className="video-list media">

                <div className="media-left">
                    <img className="media-object" src={imageUrl} />
                </div>

                <div className="media-body">
                    <div className="media-heading">{video.snippet.title}</div>  
                </div>

           </div>
        </li>
    )
    }
}
```

But I receive the error that: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined". 
And onClick event does not fire up at all in this case. How can I toggle the class when clicking on this

?

Comment: Your issue here is that in a constructor, where no values have been set, you are accessing `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`. Can you start be removing that and see what happens and post the issue(s) here? And, `() => onVideoSelect(video);` - what is it that you think this line does?

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you should write:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

OR definition of *onClick* should be:

```
onClick = (event) =>  {}
```

These two ways bind the context `this` to the function. Arrow function implicitly bind `this` to the function.

Answer (score 0):

bind also your onClick method in the constructor, and check you onClick method.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      animate: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this); 
}

onClick(event) {
    this.props.onVideoSelect(video);
    this.handleClick();
}
```